# How to remove round corners from menu layout, and add line between items?

Tags: android, xml, layout, menuitem

I just try to found here on stack overflow about menu item layout, I inflate a menu using `onCreateOptionsMenu`, but the menu has round borders when it show up, after click.

How to remove round corners and make it a square or rectangle with no borders? And if is possible put line(divisor) between items.

Here is my xml file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:context="br.com.kunzler.feedback.ResearchesActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/action_add"
      android:title="@string/nav_add"
      android:orderInCategory="101"
      app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_delete"
      android:title="@string/nav_delete"
      android:orderInCategory="102"
      app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

I try check if has background options on item tag but dont has this option.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For add line between items put items in some different groups.
For round corners check your navigationView !

Answer (score 0):

You can add this parameter inside your drawer layout
**app:drawerLayoutCornerSize="0dp"**
or  you can create a custom  menu layout, and include that inside drawer
layout